# The repository 'https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com kinetic Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

Now i have seen alot of answers on net and i could not find any answer for a repo that's not a ppa registered repo.
I am using Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic
[This is the error message i keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPKKm.png)

I also checked if the repo exists in etc/apt/sources.list and it wasn't there
kindly help as it gives me error while upgrading to ubuntu 23 version

Comment: In short, the repository does not host packages for your version of Ubuntu. You will have to remove it

Comment: This is what we call a ppa, you cannot use it, remove this ppa from your system or disable it. Also check files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu products using the *year* format are *snap* only and don't use PPAs; they are also only released on the *even* years thus there is no Ubuntu Core 23.